# Responsive Image With An Overlay Text Stay on The Same Position

Tags: html, css

I would like to  add an overlay text over an image, that the text cannot go outside the image but always inside the image even I zoom in or zoom out in my browser or I view that in different devices.

Also, an image with 100 percent width and height and the text always on the same position even using different device. Using **only** CSS and HTML the way that every framework do such Bootstrap, MaterializeCSS, Foundation, SemanticUI etc .

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* for IE 6 */
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 span {
  color: white;
  font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://www.thepoortraveler.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Banaue-Rice-Terraces.jpg" alt="Banaue Banaue-Rice-Terraces" />
  <h1><span>The Summer Capital of the Philippines<br />Baguio City</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `h1` need to be centered?

Comment: Yes, centered above the image. I use the https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/ blog as my reference. Pardon if I pick this  sites as my reference  but I thinks it's useful. @Tesseract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /* for IE 6 */
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 span {
  color: white;
  font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://www.thepoortraveler.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Banaue-Rice-Terraces.jpg" alt="Banaue Banaue-Rice-Terraces" />
  <h1><span>The Summer Capital of the Philippines<br />Baguio City</span></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will center `<h1>` even when resizing the relative `<div>`

```
h1 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50%; 
   left: 50%; 
   transform:translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```